# How do I debug a 'malformed request'?

Tags: c#, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, malformed

I am using PayPal REST API with Visual Studio 2015.  I am getting a 'malformed request' on my Sandbox paying with a paypal stored ccard (passing a token to the paypal api).
Debug ID:5b98f22095ba7

How do I capture the request as it is submitted to PayPal, so I can compare that with the expected request format?  Alternately, can someone point me to a tool that will give me detail on my debug ID?

Thanks!

?details
{PayPal.Api.Details}
    fee: "0.00"
    gift_wrap: "0.00"
    handling_fee: "0.00"
    insurance: "0.00"
    shipping: "0.00"
    shipping_discount: "0.00"
    subtotal: "55.00"
    tax: "2.75"

?paypalItem
{PayPal.Api.Item}
    category: null
    currency: "CAD"
    description: "Individual Lesson"
    height: null
    length: null
    name: "LetsRide: Individual Lesson"
    postback_data: null
    price: "55.00"
    quantity: "1"
    sku: "1"
    supplementary_data: null
    tax: "2.75"
    url: null
    weight: null
    width: null
?amnt
{PayPal.Api.Amount}
    currency: "CAD"
    details: {PayPal.Api.Details}
    total: "57.75"
?pInfo
{PayPal.Api.PayerInfo}
    billing_address: null
    birth_date: null
    buyer_account_number: null
    country_code: null
    email: null
    external_remember_me_id: null
    first_name: "Test"
    last_name: "User"
    middle_name: null
    payer_id: "test"
    phone: null
    phone_type: null
    salutation: null
    shipping_address: null
    suffix: null
    tax_id: null
    tax_id_type: null
?payr
{PayPal.Api.Payer}
    account_age: null
    account_type: null
    external_selected_funding_instrument_type: null
    funding_instruments: Count = 1
    funding_option: null
    funding_option_id: null
    payer_info: {PayPal.Api.PayerInfo}
    payment_method: "credit_card"
    related_funding_option: null
    status: null
?phn
{PayPal.Api.Phone}
    country_code: "+1"
    extension: null
    national_number: "3066920xxx"  // redacted
{PayPal.Api.Payee}
    email: "valid email adress - redacted"
    merchant_id: "valid merchant id - redacted"
    phone: null

?payment
{PayPal.Api.Payment}
    billing_agreement_tokens: null
    cart: null
    create_time: null
    experience_profile_id: null
    failed_transactions: null
    failure_reason: null
    id: null
    intent: "sale"
    links: null
    note_to_payer: null
    payee: {PayPal.Api.Payee}
    payer: {PayPal.Api.Payer}
    payment_instruction: null
    redirect_urls: null
    state: null
    token: null
    transactions: Count = 1

## update_time: null

```
               intentStr = "sale";

                // Now create Payer object and assign the fundinginstrument list to the object
                PayerInfo pInfo = new PayerInfo();
                pInfo.first_name = orderMaster.FirstName;
                pInfo.last_name = orderMaster.LastName;
                pInfo.payer_id = user.UserName;
                Payer payr = new Payer();
                payr.payer_info = pInfo;
                payr.funding_instruments = CreatePayPalFundingInstrumentList(PPCCToken);
                payr.payment_method = "credit_card";
                Phone phn = new Phone();
                phn.country_code = "+1";
                phn.national_number = userCompany.paypalPhone;
                Payee pyee = new Payee();
                pyee.email = userCompany.paypalEmail;
                pyee.merchant_id = userCompany.paypalMerchantId;

                // finally create the payment object and assign the payer object & transaction list to it
                payment = new Payment()
                {
                    intent = intentStr,    // `sale` or `authorize`
                    payer = payr,
                    payee = pyee,
                    transactions = GetTransactionsList(orderMaster)
                };
```

Comment: Were you able to intercept the payload being sent with Fiddler?

Comment: Thanks mj - I have not worked with Fiddler before, but will definitely invest some time to try to learn how to use it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self-solved:  I removed the 'payee = pyee' section that I created for third party payments, and I received a clearer error message from the paypal api.
The error was related to the test credit card I was using, not supporting CAD currency!!

Man - spend two days trying to debug code!!!!!

Captured a different test credit card in the vault, and problem solved!

Wish paypal could be clearer with their messaging on an error!  Or - give developers access to the Debug ID detail.